# jquery mobile bug on click hyperlink button inside header / footer

Tags: jquery, mobile, header, footer

I found a bug in jquery mobile, and it is reproducible in its demo version.

Goto [demo url](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/toolbars/docs-headers.html), and click on "any hyperlink button" in toolbar (with black background). It will redirect to a new page.
At the new page --> click "Back" button , it will redirect to previous page with **MISSING header**.

I could easily resolve this by moving the hyperlink to div data-role="content" -- but this is not what I want..

Is there any idea how to resolve this?

Thanks,
wan

Comment: on which browser / mobile? its fine in web(firefox and chrome). thats means it must be specific broswer related issue.

Comment: Have the same problem with safari... any idea ?
You can find the solution here : http://forum.jquery.com/topic/layout-of-home-page-gets-screwed-up-in-safari-and-mobilesafari-when-using-the-jquery-mobile-back-button

Comment: Same problem here. I have a navbar with no links in my header. (i bind click events from JavaScript so I don't need the hrefs). Coming back to the previous page wich has a text only header -> no text shown.

Comment: I tried to workaround this issue by setting the text to the h1 inside the header from the `pageshow` event callback. When this line of code is executed, the element still correctly contains the text from the previous time the page was shown. So JQM messes up and removes the text from the h1 element AFTER calling `pageshow`.